# Python: Running a strip of code unless imported

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have a file that I'm importing into my program (say a file with dictionaries). At the beginning of this file I want to put a strip of code which prints that this is not the main file and then `exit()`. The problem  I find is that this code is being run on import of the dictionaries module which I don't want happening. How to prevent that?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
if not Main_file:
    print('These aren\'t the droids you\'re looking for')
    exit()
```

in the main file there would of course be `Main_file = True` before import.

Comment: You're looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `__name__` special variable to check if your module is used as main:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('These aren\'t the droids you\'re looking for')
    exit()
```

Comment: print argument is not string

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - did't check, just copied from the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

`if __name__ == '__main__'` can identify whether this is the main file.